# Adobe Illustrator и пакетный экспорт в SVG

Tags: illustrator

Есть файл (Ai и EPS) с иконками, которые расположены на одном листе в ряд, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно пакетно экспортировать каждую иконку по отдельности? Пробовал пару скриптов, MultiExporter.jsx и SVG Exporter.jsx, первый делает видимость работы, но в итоге ни одного файла не экспортирует. Может, есть какой-то хороший и рабочий скрипт для этого, или как-то другому можно наименьшими усилиями/действиями экспортировать все значки на листе по отдельности?

Вопрос можно сказать решён, с помощью двух скриптов.

Comment: предлагаю написать небольшой скрипт, который распиливает одну svg на несколько, по определенным критерям, или же можно использовать одну svg как атлас, но это уже overhead при рендеринге

Comment: Нужно готовое решение.

Comment: В смысле готовое решение? вы пришли на ресурс посвещенный проблемам программирования, я Вам написал как можно это решить, если Вам нужен код, то Вам в свою очередь необходимо предостааить хотя бы входные данные